# Unable to use Homebrew using Rosetta on Mac M1

Tags: macos, homebrew

I made a copy of the Terminal for running apps with Rosetta following the steps from [this blogpost](https://osxdaily.com/2020/11/18/how-run-homebrew-x86-terminal-apple-silicon-mac/).

I already had installed Homebrew for M1 based apps. In the Rosetta terminal, I installed Homebrew using:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

But when running

```
>>> which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

This means I am still not running `brew` using Rosetta.

Also,

```
>>> where brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

How to switch to the Homebrew in the location `/usr/local/bin/brew` in the Rosetta terminal?

Comment: I have no M1 Mac, so I cannot test, but if e.g. `uname` gives different output under Rosetta, maybe you could use that to set different paths?

Comment: It's not clear how you know which is which, but the trivial solution is to remove `/opt/homebrew/bin` from your `PATH` in the Rosetta terminal. Alternatively, `alias brew=/usr/local/bin/brew` but this will only affect the interactive shell. (I would still not be entirely confident that `/usr/local/bin/brew` is the one you just installed.)